# How to run a program on startup with admin access from registry, before user logs on

Tags: windows-10, batch, windows-registry, regedit

I'm working on a tool that can change the password for an account without having to log in (account recovery). My thought was to put a key that runs a batch file in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce`. The batch file would contain `net user password`. 
**This would all be set up via a WinPE drive (A bootable Windows installation enviornment with access to the registry.** **However, the `RunServicesOnce` is not in my registry.** In `HKLM\Software\Microsoft` there is no `CurrentVersion` path. It needs to work on 64 and 32 bit machines (Windows 10). What is the path to these keys?

I also assumed that putting it in the `RunServicesOnce` would make it **run one time then never again**, but from what I've read online it will run **every time the computer starts**. How is this different than the `RunServices` entry?

Answer (score 0):

Some inaccuracies in your post:

- The registry keys are common for both 64 and 32 bit Windows
- In `HKLM\Software\Microsoft` there is no `CurrentVersion` sub-key, since it is in
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
- The difference between the `Once` and non-`Once` keys is that the programs in
  the `Once` keys execute before all non-`Once` programs.
  `Once` is a bad name, it should really have been named `First` or `Before`.

Comment: I was able to find the path you referred to, however there is still no `RunServiceOnce` in there. There is `RunOnce` but those run *after* log on.

Comment: A lot of the documentation about those keys dates from Windows versions preceding Windows NT. I also scanned all my registry hives and didn't find any keys named `RunServicesOnce` or `RunServices`. I would guess that they are deprecated in later versions of Windows, so I wouldn't count on them being used if you created them.

Comment: At least in regards to runonce, the items In there are run only once. A non-error return code tells windows to remove the item and it will disappear from the registry.

Comment: @Appleoddity: More complete from Microsoft: "By default, the value of a RunOnce key is deleted before the command line is run. You can prefix a RunOnce value name with an exclamation point (!) to defer deletion of the value until after the command runs. Without the exclamation point prefix, if the RunOnce operation fails the associated program will not be asked to run the next time you start the computer."

Comment: So is there no way to run a program on the startup before login? That seems rather silly.

Comment: You can [schedule it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491478/165358).

Comment: Is it possible to schedule from a winpe enviornment? Task Scheduler does use the registry for all of it's data, so it must be somewhere...